# Prototype: Array.first(); and Array[0] brings Array[1]; but I need Array[0] (Prototype code generated with Ruby On Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs

I'm currently working on a tabbar with Prototype.

Code is here:
http://teamforger.com/network/setup_tab_bar_prototype
http://teamforger.com/network/setup_tab_bar_prototype?branch=Internet

(the site generates two scripts one general and one when a keyword is entered in a search-text-field and passed as params[:branch])

Everything works super! Except these lines (when params[:branch].blank? is true) in function finalize_setup:

```
$("list_" + this.tabs.first()).setStyle({'background-color':'silver'});
$(this.tabs.first()).show();
```

`this.tabs.first()` or `this.tabs[0]` brings the content of `this.tabs[1]`

So I do this:

```
alert(this.tabs);
```

This brings

> IT,Internet

And

```
this.tabs.first(); # -> "Internet"
this.tabs[0]; # -> "Internet"
```

But "Internet" is `this.tabs[1]`

Any clues?

Thanks and best wishes,
Joern.

Comment: You say `this.tabs[0]` yields `"Internet"`, then argue that `"Internet"` should be in `this.tabs[1]`. Am I missing something?

Comment: the array is "IT", "Internet"; so array[0] should bring "IT", but it returns "Internet", which is array[1]

Comment: the problem is solved; for all who are trying to make CustomFont write something like "your mother" (I can see it in the log), here you can experiment with CustomFont: http://www.9thsky.info/custom_font

Answer (score 0):

OMFG... an Array.reverse(); has done the trick, but I'm still wondering why alert(this.tabs) brings the same order that I expect after an Array.reverse();